# Pygame shows image letters mirrored

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

Can you please help me understand why pygame shows my image as mirrored? Please see the attached image for more info:

[image]

I am capturing an image from PiCamera into PiRGBArray stream, then creating a pygame surface module and displaying the image.

This is the code:

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

pygame.init()
lcdDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((480,640))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="rgb", 
    image = frame.array

    surf=pygame.surfarray.make_surface(image)
    lcdDisplay.blit(surf, (0,0))    

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()

    # clear the stream 
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Comment: you call: `pygame.display.flip()`. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip

Comment: the display.flip does not do anything, I was hoping that it may help but no

Comment: When I show the image by opencv cv2.imshow than the image is normal

Comment: `pygame.display.flip()` just updates the window similar to `pygame.display.update()`. If you want to flip the image/surface in pygame, you can use [`pygame.transform.flip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip).

Comment: yeap pygam.transform.flip makes flip, but still the letters are shown mirrored in the picuture((

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing the image from a camera, and a camera is not a mirror :-)

Think of it this way: if the camera is facing front, and you take a picture, it'll look "correct". If you flip it to face it towards you, the image is flipped.

This is not related to pygame, it's just how cameras (webcams) work.

Comment: Can you please explain more, not sure that I got your point. Just pay attention to the fact that cv2.imshow on the same image works fine

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that good at explaining, but if you google a bit you'll find lots of links, for example http://www.rawinfopages.com/tips/2014/04/choose-normal-or-flipped-webcam-images/ .

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience on this but as far as I understand from documentation there are ways to control your camera to flip the video or not, here is comments from [tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/CameraIntro.html) :

> **Using Camera Controls**
>
> Most cameras support controls like flipping the image and changing brightness. 
>   set_controls() and get_controls() can be used at any point after using start().
>
> `cam.set_controls(hflip = True, vflip = False)`

Hope this is your case.

The other strange thing I noticed in your code is when you define camera you use resolution (640, 480), but when defining the display yo use (480, 640), is this intentional or just and error ?

Also there is similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642586/6420643) which might help you more. It has link to nice [blog](http://blog.danielkerris.com/?p=225) on same topic.

Comment: pygame takes (w,h) but  camera takes (h,w) thus the resolution difference. The camera controlling stuff just tried, doesnt help((